# Output of autocomplete populated from mysql tables

Tags: php, mysql

My textboxes get autocomplete populated from mysql tables.

I want to display the output list from the textbox into a selectable option instead of an list item.

```
echo '<li onClick="fill(\''.$result->naam_klant.'\');">'.$result->naam_klant.'</li>';
```

My code so far:

```
'<select onClick="fill(\''.$result->naam_klant.'\');"><option value=$result->naam_klant></option></select>';
```

Can you guys help me with this ?

**UPDATE**

```
    if(isset($_POST['queryString'])) {
         $queryString = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['queryString']);
        // Is the string length greater than 0?
        if(strlen($queryString) >0) {
            $query = $db->query("SELECT naam_klant FROM overboekingen WHERE naam_klant LIKE '$queryString%' LIMIT 10");     
            if($query) {
                 while ($result = $query ->fetch_object()) {
                     echo '<li onClick="fill(\''.$result->naam_klant.'\');">'.$result->naam_klant.'</li>';
                    '<select onClick="fill(\''.$result->naam_klant.'\');"><option value=$result->naam_klant></option></select>';
                }
            } else {
                echo 'ERROR: There was a problem with the query.';
            }
        } else {

        } // There is a queryString.
    } else {
        echo 'There should be no direct access to this naam_klant script!';
    }   
}

?>
```

Comment: You really have a lot of syntax and logical errors in your code.

Comment: Any advise on this ? the code is working fine as it is.

Comment: No it isn't. As I told you there a lot of syntax and logical errors.

Answer (score 1):

You don't give enough information, how you is your results structured?

```
<select onchange="fill(this.value);" onfocus="this.selectedIndex = -1;">
<? 
    for ($i=0; $i < count(results); $i++) { 
        $result = results[i];
        echo "<option value='{$result->naam_klant}'>option {$result->naam_klant}</option>\r\n";
    }  
?>
</select>
```

**Update**

Since you want a *selectable option **instead** of an list item*

```
if ($query) {
   echo '<select onchange="fill(this.value);" onfocus="this.selectedIndex = -1;">\r\n';
   while ($result = $query->fetch_object()) {
         echo '<option value={$result->naam_klant}>{$result->naam_klant}</option>\r\n';
   }
   echo '</select>\r\n';
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your efford, basicly I want the selected item from the list to apear inside the textbox when you click on it. With using <li> this was not possible so I tought I would need to use a <select><option>. It now shows up as a dropdownlist but when I click on it it still wont show in the textbox.

Comment: @user3455717 This is a different question, your `php` maybe worked for the list items ,but the one you post it and suppose to print the select options was completed wrong. Your new question has nothing to do with populating your html , it has to do with your javascipt. If your html code is properly populated with the code I provided to you, then you should target there for the error, preferably in a new question, with your javascript code printed.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will open a new question for this that is related to javascript only.

Comment: @user3455717 Apart from your javascript code paste also your select and textbox html code.